# Dialog with check boxes in android

Tags: android

I would like to know how can I implement dialog with list of elements where I can select only 4 checkboxes. How can I do that? Any tutorials?
I have something like that:

```
protected void showSelectMeasurementsDialog() {
      boolean[] checkedMeasurements = new boolean[measurements.length];
      int count = measurements.length;

      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)

              checkedMeasurements[i] = selectedMeasurements.contains(measurements[i]);

      DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener measurementsDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecselectedMeasurementsChecked){
           if(isChecselectedMeasurementsChecked)

                   selectedMeasurements.add(measurements[which]);



          else{
            selectedMeasurements.remove(measurements[which]);

          }

          onChangeSelectedMeasurements();
        }
       };

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("Select Measurements");
      builder.setMultiChoiceItems(measurements, checkedMeasurements, measurementsDialogListener);

      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();
    }
```

but I don't know how can I block selecting items when I have 4 selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this way.

```
public void dialog(View v){
String str[] = {"yyyy","xxxx","ccccc","cxcxxc","dadfssaas"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,str);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    final boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[str.length];
    alertDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(str, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
                // loop through the checkedItems array, if checkedItems
                // increment count*/

                if (checkedItems[i]) {

                    count++;

                }
                if (count == 5) {
                    // if the number of checked items become
                    // four, set the last checkedItems item 'which'
                    // to false and uncheck the checkbox
                    checkedItems[which] = false;
                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, false);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement a checkable list view as shown
   [here](http://blog.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/).
2. Keep a `Collection` of the items that have been checked in the
   Adapter (by implementing `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for the
   checkbox contained in the list item, and adding it to this
   collection each time an item is checked.
3. Finally, use the size of
   this collection to determine allowing / disallowing the checkbox to
   be clicked.

Comment: I have a problem with second step. Can you help me with that? Where I can implement setOnCheckedChaneListener?

Comment: Each list item contains a checkbox. Retrieve it in the getView method `CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) result.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);`, then set the listener on the checkbox.

Comment: ok, I have something like that:   `CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
  chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked)
     list.add(item.getId());
    
   }
  });` but how can I disallowing other checkboxs to be clicked?